# Blade - How to @push content to start of a @stack?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

In blade, you can create stacks. See the following for more information:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#stacks

However the above link only shows how to push elements to the end of the stack. 
I want to append an element to the start of the stack. How can I do this?

e.g.

```
@push('foo')pizza @endpush
@push('foo')like @endpush
@push('foo')I @endpush
@stack('foo')
```

outputs:

```
pizza like I
```

I want it to output:

```
I like pizza
```

Comment: I think they are meant just to group views, for array values alike you'd be better off with array_pop

Answer (score 1):

This is something that I wouldn't recommend doing because this is the way Laravel is built.

But, if for any reason, you need it so much and you don't see any other way to accomplish it, You can tweak the framework itself.

The file `Factory.php` is located in `Illuminate\View`. over there you have a function called `extendPush()` and you can change the "Append" method by replacing the line:

```
$this->pushes[$section][$this->renderCount] .= $content;
```

with this:

```
$this->pushes[$section][$this->renderCount] = $content . $this->pushes[$section][$this->renderCount];
```

in the last else statement.

Again, I wouldn't recommend tweaking the framework but if it's that important to your project than this is what I can offer.

Comment: It's unfortunate that the Laravel developers ignored the technical meanings and made a directive `@stack` that implements a queue. But Laravel now has a `@prepend` directive that can be used in place of `@push` to make `@stack` act as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can create in your blade `@stack`s  everywhere. If you like a stack in the header put in your blade:

```
<head>
...
@stack('myScriptsAbove')
...
</head>
```

Then you can push the scripts from other blades to it. Like that `@push('myScriptsAbove`)`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the Parent-Blade file's `@push(...)`, did somehow append after that of Child-Blade file.

But nowadays, we can simply use `@prepend`, like:

```php
@prepend('css')
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
@endprepend
```

> Seems in Blade, `@stack` works like `LIFO` queue (Last-In-First-Out);
>
> So, `@push` and `@prepend` each do the exact opposite of what I did expect.